# Unity, Xcode and clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

I ma trying to build my project to iPhone but I keep getting this error:

> ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from /Volumes/MacBackup1/AppsProduction/MyGame/Builds/iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
>   ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Volumes/MacBackup1/AppsProduction/MyGame/Builds/iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
>   ld: '/Volumes/MacBackup1/AppsProduction/MyGame/Builds/iOS/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKLikeBoxView.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Volumes/MacBackup1/AppsProduction/MyGame/Builds/iOS/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit' for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have been looking around for an answer, and there is a lot of post regarding clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation), but none seems to work in my case.

I am stuck at this moment and are hoping for some help. Any help is appreciated.

I am using Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b) and Unity3D 2017.3.0p4. I am also using the latest Facebook SDK (v7.11.0) for Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling Bit code in Build Setting

[image]

Comment: Ahh, that got me passed the error, but I got a lot of new errors :-/ What does Bitcode do?